# How to ignore a jest mock after the first test when testing react reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-testing-library

I am using the react-testing-library

I am using react-cookies in my reducer to load a user. I want to mock react-cookies, so I can load a fake user to my reducer when I am testing. However, I only want to mock react-cookies in the first test, because in the 2nd test I want the cookie to return undefined which the original implementation of react-cookies does. So I have react-cookies in a mocks folder in my tests. So I am mocking the entire module react-cookies.

But I want the 2nd test to ignore that I am mocking react-cookies. But I have tried `jest.RequireActual, jest.unmock, jest.deepUnmock` and none of those work and my test always uses the mock implementation of react-cookies.

The test file:

```
describe('reducer', () => {
  afterEach(() => {jest.unmock('react-cookies')  });

  test('should return initialState when user is defined ', () => {
    expect(authentication(undefined, {})).toEqual(
      {
        user: {
         name: "Smith",
        },
      })
  })

  test('should return initialState when user is undefined', () => {
    expect(authentication(undefined, {})).toEqual(
      {
        user: undefined,
      }
    )
  })
})
```

Here is the react-cookies file in **mocks** folder:

```
export default {
    load: jest.fn()
    .mockReturnValue(
          {
                name: "Smith"
            })
       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just mock it directly inside your test?
Something like:

```
import * as cookies from 'react-cookies';

cookies.load = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    name: 'Smith'
});

cookies.load.mockClear();
```

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
jest.mock('react-cookies', () => ({
  load: jest.fn() //and mock implementation if you wish
}))
```

Comment: I am receiving an error because `cookies.load.mockClear();` is not a function and when I mock the function that way, the test does not run the mocked function

Comment: Is there another way I could mock cookies.load?

Comment: I still get undefined in my reducer when I load the user

Comment: It works when I put the mock function outside my describe statement, but for the 2nd test I want to remove the mock

Comment: As stated above, restore the mock after test

Comment: I do that but the test still uses the mock function

Comment: Even if you assign the whole `'react-cookies'` mock to a variable and the restore its mock?